# getServerSideProps() not running using component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a small web app with Next.js and I'm not sure why, but `getServerSideProps()` isn't running when I use the component. I previously had the following code on a page in `/pages`, but I moved it to use as a component.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  console.log("in getServerSideProps") // never shows
  let bans = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/get_bans').then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })

  return {
    props: { bans: bans }
  }

}

const BansList = (listName, bans) => {
  
  bans = bans.bans
  console.log(bans) // undefined
  
  return (
    <h1>test</h1>
  )

}
```

I've stripped the code down to easily show what's wrong. When I use that as a component `getServerSideProps` isn't run, so `bans` is always undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe `getServerSideProps ` works only in Components under pages folder.

Comment: You're not accessing the props correctly in the `BansList` component, it should be: `const BansList = ({ listName, bans })`.

Answer (score 9):

`getServserSideProps` only works on page-level, not component level. You have to use a page component under `pages/`
[image]

More info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Answer (score -1):

And not only that, you should use curly braces ( ie destructuration ) to use the props spreaded from getServerSideProps by their names.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).